# Expand div to max width when float:left is set

Tags: html, width

I have something like that:

```
<div style="width:100px;float:left">menu</div>
<div style="float:left">content</div>
```

both floats are neccesary. I want the content div to fill the whole screen minus those 100px for the menu. If i dont use float the div expands exactly as it should. But how do i set this when float is set? If i use sth like

```
style=width:100%
```

then the content div gets the size of the parent, which is either the body or another div which i also tried, and so of course it does not fit right of the menu and is then shown below.

Answer (score 143, accepted):

Hope I've understood you correctly, take a look at this: http://jsfiddle.net/EAEKc/

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Content with Menu</title>
  <style>
    .content .left {
      float: left;
      width: 100px;
      background-color: green;
    }
    
    .content .right {
      margin-left: 100px;
      background-color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="left">
      <p>Hi, Flo!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <p>is</p>
      <p>this</p>
      <p>what</p>
      <p>you are looking for?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: The question states "both floats are neccesary".

Comment: Yes, you are right and I agree. However I think Flo only mentioned this, because he thinks they are both! needed to get the desired layout and therefore my alternative solution.

Comment: @merkuro: good point. I agree, ".right" does not need to be floated to get the desired effect. @Flo: can you confirm, must the content div be floated? Like for other reasons?

Comment: might work i will try a little around with that, you got that reason right, and the float is nicer, but i figure it just wont work

Comment: Ahh jeah and i again see the reason why i changed it to float:
Ie7 and Firefox do fine, but ie 5.5 and ie 6 start the margin at the right edge of the left div, so it has a 236px (the real width, 100 was an example) gap between both divs

Comment: ok as i dont really need a padding here i just let the margin be. The only Problem then is, that the first subdiv of the right div needs has a padding issue, but even if its dirty i will just use an empty div for left-padding (others work). css is sick.

Comment: Is there a way to do this when one is using `border-box` sizing?

Comment: I was doing the opposite, (right static, left filling the space). had to move the right element first in the html

Answer (score 103):

The most cross-compatible way I've found of doing this is not very obvious.  You need to remove the float from the second column, and apply `overflow:hidden` to it.  Although this would seem to be hiding any content that goes outside of the div, it actually forces the div to stay within its parent.

Using your code, this is an example of how it could be done:

```
<div style="width: 100px; float: left;">menu</div>
<div style="overflow: hidden;">content</div>
```

Hope this is useful to anyone having this issue, it's what I found works the best for the site I was building, after trying to get it to adjust to other resolutions.  Unfortunately, this doesn't to work if you include a right-floated `div` after the content as well, if anyone knows a good way to get that to work, with good IE compatibility, I'd be very happy to hear it.

### New, better option using `display: flex;`

Now that the Flexbox model is fairly widely implemented, I'd actually recommend using it instead, since it allows much more `flex`ibility with the layout. Here's a simple two-column like the original:

```
<div style="display: flex;">
    <div style="width: 100px;">menu</div>
    <div style="flex: 1;">content</div>
</div>
```

And here's a three-column with a flexible-width center column!

```
<div style="display: flex;">
    <div style="width: 100px;">menu</div>
    <div style="flex:1;">content</div>
    <div style="width: 100px;">sidebar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: After some further testing, it appears that you don't need to trigger hasLayout with "position: relative" for this to work in IE 6, I'm not sure about IE 5, but it's generally not a problem to include it anyway, just to be safe.

Comment: This answers seems unappreciated, but it is really good to know.
This one does let you float, even with a floating element inside the div.
I'ma google "block formatting context." right now.

Comment: The best way is to use a simple 2 cols table instead of wasting time adding tons of CSS not-cross-browser-compatibles tricks

Comment: @Marco I needed to use CSS for this as my design is responsive. Different screen sizes needed different layouts, so a table would not have worked. Also, this method appears to work in basically any browser anyone still uses.

Comment: @alanaktion: IMHO table width adapts perfectly to different screen sizes (`<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" style="width:100%;">`). Anyway if you feel more confortable entering into your house through the window rather than by using the door, it's your choice.

Comment: @MarcoDemaio, my point was that on a screen size where the smaller fixed column would be about as large as the main column, such as on a mobile device, I wanted the two columns to become full-width rows, which could not be done with tables unless I wanted to actually move content around with JavaScript.

Comment: I have a very similar situation and the answer worked well for me. I also needed some offset between the two divs. For some reason, adding margin-left to the 2nd div did not work (would love to know the theory behind this), but adding an inner div into the 2nd div, and setting that inner div's margin, worked just fine.

Comment: IMHO the best answer as it is nearly dynamically. For my solution I have removed the width so it always fits for me.

Comment: @MarcoDemaio, I agree with "alanaktion". Usually people who are looking for solutions for expanding divs to take the remaining width also want be able to change the div to full width on mobile devices. So on wide screen, the two divs are on one row and two columns, but on smaller screen, they want it to be two rows but one column. This cannot be simply implemented by table element.

Answer (score 31):

### Solution without fixing size on your margin

```
.content .right{
    overflow: auto; 
    background-color: red;
}
```

+1 for Merkuro, but if the size of the float changes your fixed margin will fail.
If u use above CSS on the right `div` it will nicely change size with changing size on the left float. It is a bit more flexible like that.
Check the fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/9ZHBK/144/

Comment: @alanaktion I took the unnecessary auto away. The difference is in the overflow value. Apparently `overflow: hidden` and `overflow auto` result in the same behavior. I also think people appreciate the Fiddle.

Comment: If anyone wants to know why this works, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1767270/2756409

Comment: I think this is better than merkuro's solution.

Answer (score 6):

Elements that are floated are taken out of the normal flow layout, and block elements, such as DIV's, no longer span the width of their parent. The rules change in this situation. Instead of reinventing the wheel, check out this site for some possible solutions to create the two column layout you are after: http://www.maxdesign.com.au/presentation/page_layouts/

Specifically, the "Liquid Two-Column layout".

Cheers!

Answer (score 5):

this usage may solve your problem.

```
width: calc(100% - 100px);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <title>Content with Menu</title>
  <style>
    .content .left {
      float: left;
      width: 100px;
      background-color: green;
    }
    
    .content .right {
      float: left;
      width: calc(100% - 100px);
      background-color: red;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="content">
    <div class="left">
      <p>Hi, Flo!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right">
      <p>is</p>
      <p>this</p>
      <p>what</p>
      <p>you are looking for?</p>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Could you add an explanation as to how this works?

Answer (score 4):

*This is an updated solution for HTML 5 if anyone is interested & not fond of "floating".*

Table works great in this case as you can set the fixed width to the table & table-cell.

```
.content-container{
    display: table;
    width: 300px;
}

.content .right{
    display: table-cell;   
    background-color:green;
    width: 100px;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EAEKc/596/ 
original source code from @merkuro

Comment: +1 finally something that works with the fixed width element to the right, even if it doesnt technically use float.

Comment: +1 so totally yes. after years of struggling with floats and positions and tables, this is the right solution. the accepted solution propagates unsafe css.

Answer (score 3):

And based on `merkuro`'s solution, if you would like maximize the one on the left, you should use:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>   
<html lang="en">     
    <head>              
        <meta "charset="UTF-8" />   
        <title>Content with Menu</title>                 
        <style>
            .content .left {
                margin-right: 100px;
                background-color: green;
            }
            .content .right {
                float: right;
                width: 100px;
                background-color: red;
            }
        </style>              
    </head>
    <body>        
        <div class="content">
            <div class="right">  
                <p>is</p>
                <p>this</p>
                <p>what</p>
                <p>you are looking for?</p>
            </div>
            <div class="left">
                <p>Hi, Flo!</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Has not been tested on IE, so it may look broken on IE.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer might work, but I don't like the idea of overlapping margins. In HTML5, you would do this with `display: flex;`. It's a clean solution. Just set the width for one element and `flex-grow: 1;` for the dynamic element. An edited version of merkuros fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/EAEKc/1499/

Answer (score 0):

This might work:

```
    div{
    display:inline-block;
    width:100%;
    float:left;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi there is an easy way with overflow hidden method on right element.

```css
    .content .left {
        float:left;
        width:100px;
        background-color:green;
      }
      .content .right {
        overflow: hidden;
        background-color:red;
      }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>   
<html lang="en">     
    <head>      
           
        <title>Content Menu</title>         
          
    </head>
    <body>    
    <div class="content">
      <div class="left">
        <p>Hi, Flo! I am Left</p>
      </div>
      <div class="right">  
        <p>is</p>
        <p>this</p>
        <p>what</p>
        <p>you are looking for?</p>
        <p> It done with overflow hidden and result is same.</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```