# 2 left floating divs, with fixed size and auto width

Tags: html, css

Hello i am having a problem with a CSS design. I have 2 floating div's, where the first is always 200 px width, where the second div have to be the rest of the page width.
How can this be done? i have tryed width: auto and 100%

```
<div style="float: left; width: 200px">
</div>
<div style="float: left;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closest to your example:

```
<div style="float: left; width: 200px;">
</div>
<div style="margin-left: 200px;">
</div>
```

Comment: Removed my answer. I didn't like what I was doing. +1 for you.

Answer (score 0):

It's working, but the div is adjusting to it's content which is empty right now, if you want to leave it empty, try "display:block;

Answer (score 0):

I think this might be what you are looking for.

[Expand div to max width when float:left is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017880/expand-div-to-max-width-when-floatleft-is-set)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the second `<div>`. Try this:

```
<html>
   <body>
      <div style="float: left; width: 200px; margin-right: 20px;">
          Floating Content
      </div>
      Main Content
   </body>
</html>
```

The main content will wrap around the bottom of the floating `<div>`, so if you don't want that, you'll have to set the height.

Answer (score 0):

By far the best trick here is to only `float` the  left `div`:

http://jsfiddle.net/8y2t2/

```
#left {
    width: 200px;
    float: left;
    background: #ccc
}
#right {
    background: red;
    overflow: hidden
}
<div id="left">left</div>
<div id="right">right</div>
```

A bonus from doing it this way is that you don't need to specify the width of the left `div` as both a `width` and a `margin-left` (as in other answers here). That's thanks to `overflow: hidden`.

Compare: http://jsfiddle.net/8y2t2/1/ vs http://jsfiddle.net/8y2t2/2/

If you would like multiple instances: http://jsfiddle.net/8y2t2/3/