# Problems with two side by divs and 100% height

Tags: css, height, css-float

Warning, the page contains some NSFW images.

http://neekeri.com/2012/

I'm trying to make the left div 300px width and the right one to be rest of the page.

I finally figured out how to get them stay next to each other like that, but [the fix I used](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017880/expand-div-to-max-width-when-floatleft-is-set/1017956#1017956) made the heights all weird.

HTML & CSS:
http://pastebin.com/tggteQWg

Any suggestions/ideas?

Comment: post your code here, I don't wanna load anything NSFW while @ work...

Comment: This is what I'm trying to achieve: SFW: http://i.imgur.com/gh3Hi.jpg

Answer (score 0):

In your CSS (*within div#right*), if you remove `margin-left : 300px` it should fix it. Alternatively, you can remove `overflow : scroll`.

(Don't remove them both, but try one or the other, both seem to fix your issue)

Comment: Hmm, neither of them fixed it, the #left is still not 100% height and the #right is over 100% height.