# CSS - Fill remaining width next to floated element and keep content from falling down below floated element?

Tags: css, css-float, fill

The problem i'm having is i need to float one element with a fixed width to the left, and have an element next to it fill the remaining width.

The only solution that i know of is to float the first element, and then the element next to it will automatically fill the remaining width. The problem i'm having is the following:

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/udBsx

If the green content is higher than the red, it will jump down below the red. Is there any way to prevent this from happening? I've played around with `clear` but i don't think there's anything i can do to keep it from happening.

To make it even worse, the site is responsive. If it weren't, i could just give the green element a static width and float it as well, but that is not the case. I can't use percentage because the red element has a static width.

I believe flexbox has what i'm looking for but unfortunately it's not an option right now due to lack of support.

Ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Expand div to max width when float:left is set](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017880/expand-div-to-max-width-when-floatleft-is-set)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

EDIT:

The css code should look like this:

```
.floated {
  width:200px; float:left; 
}

.fill {
  margin-left:200px;
}
```

Comment: That won't work because `.fill` should fill the remaining space of the screen, it doesn't have a static width. *Edit:* Also, what is the purpose of `.central` in your example?

Comment: ouh, ok, one sec to modify

Comment: Oooh, oh! That's smart, can't believe i didn't think of that. Let me test drive that before i accept it! :)

Comment: Wow, this would have made my life so much easier if i knew this like three weeks ago. Oh well, thank you!