# CSS for HTML dynamic layout with not fixed columns?

Tags: html, css

I want to set such layout both columns are dynamic - one is set by content second by the first column and minimum width. I found many solution where column is fixed with width but it no solves this problem.

See what I want achieve on screen.

[image]

What CSS I should use?

Answer (score 1):

There are different approaches for stuff like this ... an easy way would be to use `display: table;` for the container `display: table-cell;` for the childs and `width: 1px;` for the first child.

I have made a fiddle for you:

http://jsfiddle.net/TfuTE/

Comment: Looks that need table layout. Thanks for hint.

Answer (score 0):

check out this

http://codepen.io/Parthmy007/full/HKJuj

use Display : "table-cell" on both column or set max-width and min-width.and set first column width is "auto".