# Troubles with Div after float left

Tags: html, css-float

I'm trying to place two div horizontally, but one the content of the second div exceeds the height of the first one i get bad results:

Here is my Html code:

```
<html>
<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="mystyle.css"></head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="yellow">sometext</div>
<div class="green">more text here more text here more text here more text here more     text here more text here more text here more text here more text here more text     here </div>
<div class="spacer"></div>
</div>
</body>
```

and this is my Css:

```
.yellow {
background-color: yellow;
margin: 2px;
float: left;
width: 100px;
text-align: center;
}

.green{
background-color: #00ff00;
      }

.container {
width: 30%;
}

.spacer {
 clear: both;
}
```

The result i want is this:

[image]

but this is what i get:

[image]

Comment: Question: why is `div.yellow` green and `div.green` yellow?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not make the container background the same colour as your first div and change the CSS to:

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/AASeY/)

```
.yellow {
background-color: #00ff00;
margin: 2px;
float: left;
width: 100px;
text-align: center;
}

.green{
background-color: yellow;
    overflow: hidden;    <-- added
      }

.container {
width: 30%;
    background-color: #00ff00;  <-- added
}

.spacer {
 clear: both;
}
```

Comment: clear: both for me did the trick to avoid a Footer div getting messed with float:left before it

Answer (score 2):

Although float is commonly used for layout purposes like this, it was originally designed to **float** text elements. This is the reason for why floated divs behave in a *strange manner* when ones not familiar with it.

Beside the text formatting issues there is actually another difficulty when you want two floated elements have the same *automatic* height. This could be achieved much better by using the `display` property with `table` and `table-cell`.

Have a look at this:

[CSS for HTML dynamic layout with not fixed columns?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17256222/css-for-html-dynamic-layout-with-not-fixed-columns/17256241#17256241)

Or just take the regarding fiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/TfuTE/

Answer (score 1):

I think restricting `.container` to has a specific `background-color` may be cumbersome. 
I suggest using `display: table` for parent element and `display: table-cell` for children to get rid of this issue.

Just add following lines in your stylesheet:

```
.container {
  display: table;
  height: 100%;
}

.container > div {
  display: table-cell;
  height: inherit;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

Here is a **[JSBin Demo](http://jsbin.com/uqenit/1/edit)**

Answer (score 0):

if you make a blocklevel element float your element won't be height and width 100% but as big as it's content, or as big as you set it with css.

you could give it a height with css

you could give the yellow div a `margin-left: 104px`