# Expand middle div to remaining width when 2 divs aside as float:left and float:right

Tags: html, css, width

Please see the [fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/destan/EAEKc/773/)

The requirement is that red area should expand the remaining width automatically. The problem is blue area is not showing on top aligned.

Is there a way to achieve this without `table` and `javascript`?

Note: Very similar to question here [Expand div to max width when float:left is set](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1017880/expand-div-to-max-width-when-floatleft-is-set) but not the same. In this question there are 2 floated divs.

Comment: There is another way to solve it but it already implemented `table` with divs: http://jsfiddle.net/fa9FJ/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What if you place the `right` div before the `middle` one ?

```
<div class="content">
  <div class="left">
    <p>Hi, Flo!</p>
 </div>
 <div class="right">foo</div>
 <div class="middle">  
    <p>is</p>
    <p>this</p>
    <p>what</p>
    <p>you are looking for?</p>
  </div>
 </div>
```

See your updated [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/EAEKc/777/)

---

To explain :

Using `float` property is like using `position:absolute` property. It gets the elements out of the DOM flow. Which means they do not take any space in it.

That's why you have to set a `margin-left` property on the page content when using a `float:left` div. If not, the content will be juste under the left div.

At the oposite, your `middle` div is IN the DOM flow. So it takes all the space (because of his width AND his margin properties). So when you want to add your `float:right` div, the next available space to do it is below the `middle` div, and not anymore on the same line.

That's why, when you are using `float` properties, you have to set them before the "not-floated" content.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and updated fiddle. Do you know/explain why the order affects the rendered result like this?

Answer (score 1):

Here you go

**HTML**

```
<div class="green">some content</div>
<div class="blue">some content</div>
<div class="red">some content</div>
```

**CSS**

```
.green {
    float: right;
    width: 300px; /*if you need set the width*/
    margin: 0 0 0 10px;/*if you need set the margin*/
}
.blue {
    float: left;
    width: 300px; /*if you need set the width*/
    margin: 0 10px 0 0;/*if you need set the margin*/
}
.red {overflow: hidden;}
```